# Trouble retrieving Laravel relation as object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Baffled by what should be a fairly straightforward issue.

I have two objects related to each other:

```
class Country extends Eloquent {
    public function hotspot()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Hotspot');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Hotspot extends Eloquent {
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Country');
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve my hotspots and the countries they belong to, so:

```
$hotspot_list = Hotspot::with('country')->get();
```

As a test, I just want to loop through the list and output the country codes:

```
foreach ($hotspot_list as $hotspot_item) {
    $hotspot = $hotspot_item->country;

    echo $hotspot->country_code;
}
```

Throws an error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

So obviously I also can't do `echo $hotspot_item->country->country_code;`

If I access $hotspot as an array, it works: `echo $hotspot['country_code'];`

Because of this, I can't access $hotspot as an object. Since $hotspot is actually a Country object, I'm wanting to check another relation I have with Country but I can't since it's giving me an array instead of the object.

So even though I shouldn't have to do it this way, I tried this:

```
$country_id = $hotspot['id'];           
$country = Country::find($country_id);
echo $country->name;
```

Still no go, it's still returning as an array, so I can do `echo $country['name'];`

Suggestions?

Comment: Do all your hotspots have countries associated?  If one of them doesn't and you try to echo it as an object, it will throw an error.  If you echo it as an array, I don't believe an error will be thrown, it just won't do anything for that row.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to clarify that: yes, all hotspots have countries. I only have a handful of hotspots and I've verified in the db that they all have countries.

Comment: Well drat, I took a closer look and there is a problem with one of my countries. That's probably the issue.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks for the tip. If you'll post that as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure all your hotspots have countries, or you can validate them as you loop...

```
foreach ($hotspot_list as $hotspot_item) {
    $hotspot = $hotspot_item->country;

    if(isset($hotspot->country_code)) {
        echo $hotspot->country_code;
    }
}
```

Or even better if you have Laravel 4.1, only get the countries that have hotspots with...

`$hotspot_list = Hotspot::has('country')->get();`